# Custom Cursor Mix-Blend Mode on Hover Only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add the mix-blend-mode on Hover only. Just like this example:

[image]

Basically make the `mix-blend-mode: difference;` to work only on hover. Not sure where I can place the code. See the full code below. Thanks!!! Sorry, I can’t run a snippet here.

```js
const $bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
const $smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--small');
const $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// Listeners
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
for (let i = 0; i < $hoverables.length; i++) {
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover);
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut);
}

// Move the cursor
window.CP.exitedLoop(0);function onMouseMove(e) {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .4, {
    x: e.clientX - 15,
    y: e.clientY - 15 });

  TweenMax.to($smallBall, .1, {
    x: e.clientX - 5,
    y: e.clientY - 7 });

}

// Hover an element
function onMouseHover() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
    scale: 1.7 });

}
function onMouseHoverOut() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
    scale: 1 });

}
```

```css
body .cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
}
body .cursor__ball {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  z-index: 1000;
}

body .cursor__ball circle {
  fill: #110075;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Cursor -->
<div class="cursor">
  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big ">
    <svg height="30" width="30">
      <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
    <svg height="10" width="10">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="cursor">
  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big ">
    <svg height="30" width="30">
      <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
    <svg height="10" width="10">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  body .cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
}
body .cursor__ball {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  z-index: 1000;
}
body .cursor__ball circle {
  fill: #110075;
    }}
  

  
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script>
const $bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
const $smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--small');
const $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// Listeners
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
for (let i = 0; i < $hoverables.length; i++) {
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover);
  $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut);
}

// Move the cursor
window.CP.exitedLoop(0);function onMouseMove(e) {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .4, {
    x: e.clientX - 15,
    y: e.clientY - 15 });

  TweenMax.to($smallBall, .1, {
    x: e.clientX - 5,
    y: e.clientY - 7 });

}

// Hover an element
function onMouseHover() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
    scale: 1.7 });

}
function onMouseHoverOut() {
  TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
    scale: 1 });

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to add `mix-blend-mode: difference;` to `.cursor` and delete it from `.cursor__ball`.
2. In style of `.cursor__ball circle` change `fill:black` to `fill:white`
3. Set `background-color:white;` to `body` (without setting this it doesn't work), because `mix-blend-mode: difference;` changes colors so if body background is white then `mix-blend-mode` will change fill of `.cursor__ball circle` to opposite color so it must have `fill:white`.  Like that.

   codepen: https://codepen.io/Lukas249/pen/zYjMxRb

```js
const $bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
    const $smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--small');
    const $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll('a');

    // Listeners
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    for (let i = 0; i < $hoverables.length; i++) {
      $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover);
      $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut);
    }

    // Move the cursor

    function onMouseMove(e) {
      TweenMax.to($bigBall, .4, {
        x: e.clientX - 15,
        y: e.clientY - 15
      });

      TweenMax.to($smallBall, .1, {
        x: e.clientX - 5,
        y: e.clientY - 7
      });

    }

    // Hover an element
    function onMouseHover() {
      TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
        scale: 1.7
      });

    }
    function onMouseHoverOut() {
      TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
        scale: 1
      });

    }
```

```css
    html {
         background-color: white;
    }
    body {
      background-color: white;
    }
    body .cursor {
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    body .cursor__ball {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    body .cursor {
       mix-blend-mode: difference;
    }

    body .cursor__ball circle {
      fill: white;
    }
    
    a {
      font-size:1.5rem;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a>text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text text</a>
  <!-- Custom Cursor -->
  <div class="cursor">
    <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big ">
      <svg height="30" width="30">
        <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
      <svg height="10" width="10">
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 
</head>

<body>

<a>text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text
  text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text
  texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text
  text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text
  text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext
  text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text text text texttext text text text
  text text text</a>
<div class="cursor">
  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big ">
    <svg height="30" width="30">
      <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
    <svg height="10" width="10">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  html {
    background-color: white;
  }

  body {
    background-color: white;
  }

  body .cursor {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  body .cursor__ball {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
  }

  body .cursor {
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
  }

  body .cursor__ball circle {
    fill: white;
  }

  a {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const $bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
  const $smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--small');
  const $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll('a');

  // Listeners
  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  for (let i = 0; i < $hoverables.length; i++) {
    $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseHover);
    $hoverables[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseHoverOut);
  }

  // Move the cursor
  window.CP.exitedLoop(0); function onMouseMove(e) {
    TweenMax.to($bigBall, .4, {
      x: e.clientX - 15,
      y: e.clientY - 15
    });

    TweenMax.to($smallBall, .1, {
      x: e.clientX - 5,
      y: e.clientY - 7
    });

  }

  // Hover an element
  function onMouseHover() {
    TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
      scale: 1.7
    });

  }
  function onMouseHoverOut() {
    TweenMax.to($bigBall, .3, {
      scale: 1
    });

  }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! But it didn’t work, plus I want the cursor this color: fill: #110075; it’s confusing now...

Comment: So there’s no way to use that color #110075  without it turning into yellow? Only works if it’s black?

Comment: I updated my post, see the full code, that’s how I am adding it. I am using it on a website on Squarespace, it should be like that, not separated like the First code I added. Can you help me with that? Just by editing it as it is? Thanks!!

Comment: without it turning into yellow probably no.

Comment: Didn’t work... I did exactly what you said, but the cursor disappeared...

Comment: Thanks again, but unfortunately it didn’t work.

Comment: Here’s the site I have the cursor with my first code: https://joinscout.co/ - Notice when I hover over a link it doesn’t invert. After Adding your code, everything disappears.

Comment: I can't help with implementing this to your website. I only did what you were expecting in that question.